# Working on Word Document without Activating it

Tags: vba, object, ms-word, window

Currently I am working on **Rough.docx** where I select some text and find the selected text in a another file having named **Ticker Graveyard.Docx** (already opened). Everything works smoothly but there is a twist. I need to do all finding work silently without activating the "Ticker Graveyard.Docx" by using `Windows().Activate`.

```
Sub Ticker_Finder_Updated_2()

Dim SD As String
Dim NAME As String
Dim TICKER As String
    SD = Trim(selection.Text)

    Windows("Ticker Graveyard").Activate '''''''''''''
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With selection.Find
        .Text = SD
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
      End With
    selection.Find.Execute
    If selection.Find.Found Then
        If selection.Font.Bold = True Then
        selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
        TICKER = selection.Text
        selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
        NAME = selection.Text
        Else
        selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
        NAME = selection.Text
        selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
        TICKER = selection.Text
        End If
        selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Windows("Rough").Activate

        With selection
        .Font.Size = 9
        .TypeText (TICKER)
        .Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=1
        .Font.Size = 9
        .TypeText (NAME)
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TypeText Text:="{END}{COMPANY NEWS}"
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, COUNT:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        End With

    Else
    Windows("Rough").Activate
    selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
    End If
End Sub
```

Can it be done without creating any `WordObject`? kindly help. any-other method of doing this will b appreciated.

**Ticker Graveyard**: has 'Company Names' and their 'Tickers' in a Table so that when ever I had only name of Company in my Rough file I can catch its ticker.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily without `Window.Activate` but to use this kind of code ("interop") you do need a Word.Document object. If you were to manipulate the WordOpenXML of the second document, you could perform that on the closed file. Word-VBA, however, has no built-in tools for working with Office Open XML zip packages. It is possible, but that discussion exceeds a StackOverflow Q&A.

Since you post this in the word-vba tag I'll show you how you can work with the second file "silently" - without activating the Window in which the second document is running.

In order to move between table cells using a Range, you can work with the `MoveStart` and `MoveEnd` methods that also recognize `Unit:=wdCell`. Since you only want to pick up information if the Range is in a table, I added a check for that to the `If`.

Assuming Bold can be in only the one column, it's not necessary to move two directions. You get the first bit of information, them move to the adjaceent cell to get the second bit.

When querying a cell's `Range.Text` you're going to pick up the cell's internal structures along with the text. That appends Chr(13) & Chr(7) to the string. There are various ways to get around that - I've put one of these in a little function that trims the characters and returns the string.

```
Sub Ticker_Finder_Updated_2()

Dim SD As String
Dim NAME As String
Dim TICKER As String
    SD = Trim(selection.Text)

'Actions in document currently not active
Dim doc as Word.Document
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set doc = Application.Windows("Ticker Graveyard").Document
Set rng = doc.Content
    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    With rng.Find
        .Text = SD
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
      End With
    rng.Find.Execute
If rng.Find.found And rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    If rng.Font.Bold = True Then
      NAME = TrimCellText(rng.Cells(1).Range)
      rng.MoveStart wdCell, 1
      TICKER = TrimCellText(rng.Cells(1).Range)
    Else
      TICKER = TrimCellText(rng.Cells(1).Range)
      rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdCell, Count:=-1
      NAME = TrimCellText(rng.Cells(1).Range)
    End If

      'Actions in currently active document - would also be better with 
      'a Range specific to this document
      With selection
        .Font.Size = 9
        .TypeText (TICKER)
        .Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=1
        .Font.Size = 9
        .TypeText (NAME)
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TypeText Text:="{END}{COMPANY NEWS}"
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, COUNT:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      End With
      selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, COUNT:=1
    End If
End Sub

Function TrimCellText(r As word.Range) As String
    Dim sLastChar As String
    Dim sCellText As String

    sCellText = r.Text
    sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Do While sLastChar = Chr(7) Or sLastChar = Chr(13)
        sCellText = Left(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 1)
        sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Loop
    TrimCellText = sCellText
End Function
```